# How can I subtract two queries in sql?

Tags: sql, database

my first query returns me the value 20:

```
    SELECT numberofseats
    from plane
    where tail number in
     ( select flighttailnumberfk
       from flight
       where departuretime between '11/29/2014' and '11/30/2014' and
             flightdepartureairportfk = 'jfk' and
             flightarrivalairport = 'mli'
     )
```

and my second query returns me 1:

```
    select count(reservationseatfk)
    from flight f, reservation r
    where f.departuretime between '11/29/2014' and '11/30/2014' and
          f.reservationflightidfk = f.flightid and r.reservationdeparturetimefk = f.departuretime
```

Now my problem is that I want to subtract the first query from the second query and give me the answer 19. how do i do that?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?  `'11/29/2014'` is not a valid date literal in (standard) SQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use sub sql to subtract

```
SELECT numberofseats - ( select count(reservationseatfk)
    from flight f, reservation r
    where f.departuretime between '11/29/2014' and '11/30/2014' and
          f.reservationflightidfk = f.flightid and r.reservationdeparturetimefk = f.departuretime)
    from plane
    where tail number in
     ( select flighttailnumberfk
       from flight
       where departuretime between '11/29/2014' and '11/30/2014' and
             flightdepartureairportfk = 'jfk' and
             flightarrivalairport = 'mli'
     )
```

Comment: This worked flawlessly for me! But mind if I ask a question? How is this different from doing select (query1) - (query2)? Because I did that earlier and it did not worked for me.

Comment: you can use only one select statement (except union, minus ones). if you want to use operators like add, minus, divide etc., you need a variable. by sub select, you get variable that you want to use.

Answer (score 3):

you can do it in following way:

```
SELECT (query1) - (query2)
```

or

```
SELECT (query1)  - (query2) AS Difference
```

or

```
select @result = (query1) - (query2)
```