# Substracting average of first query from the avg of the second query

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

I would like to find the difference between the average salary of the pilots and the average salary of the employees, including pilots, so basically a (average(pilot) - average(employees)).

Though I'm having trouble combining the two SQL queries together, here's what I've managed to do so far:

```
SELECT AVG(salary) AS 'average(pilot)'
  FROM employees e, certified c
 WHERE e.EID  IN (SELECT EID FROM certified GROUP BY eid);

SELECT AVG(salary) AS 'average(employees)'
  FROM employees e, certified c
 WHERE e.EID NOT IN (SELECT EID FROM certified GROUP BY eid);
```

Now I only need to subtract the result of the second query from the first query. How do  I proceed?

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33772945/how-can-i-subtract-two-queries-in-sql) out

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  It is highly unlikely that you actually want a Cartesian product.

Comment: Hi, welcome. See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Strawberry please do read: https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/

"Too often, someone comes here to ask a question, only to be told that they did it wrong. They get snarky or condescending comments for not explaining what they’ve tried (that didn’t work). They get an answer… but the answerer gets scolded for “encouraging ‘low-quality’ questions.” They get downvoted, but don’t know why, or called lazy for not speaking English fluently. ... All these experiences add up to making SO a very unwelcoming place for far too many."

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya I've been here a while now, so I think I've got a pretty good sense of how it works - and when it works best.

Comment: @Strawberry no offense for experience or anything. Just humbly pointing to a blog written recently by a SO official. Recently I have been seeing quite a few downvotes on answers where the OP/answerer had spent sometime and somehow understood the problem. Nevertheless, that is the format of this forum. I can't change people, but I will try my best to keep on generating content.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya I see nothing 'snarky' or 'condescending' here. Case in point: The OP has accepted an answer, and in doing so, very likely missed out on a much simpler and more efficient solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select (select query2) - (select query1);
```

I guess this should work,

```
select (select avg(salary) as 'average(employees)'
from employees e, certified c
where e.EID not in (select EID from certified group by eid)) - (select  avg(salary) as 'average(pilot)'
from employees e, certified c
where e.EID  in (select EID from certified group by eid));
```

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40735190/subtract-results-of-two-select-queries-in-mysql) for similar answers

Comment: thanks, that worked perfectly, though is there a way to return positive values only?

Edit, I used abs on the first select and now it returns positive values only, thanks!

Comment: Upvoted, though since I have less then 15 rep, it doesn't show, not sure why you got downvoted though